# installing pythonsetup tools to a specific python directory

Tags: python, installation, environment-variables, setuptools

I have to work on grid for which I need to install some python packages. I was trying to install pythonsetup tools, though the grid has python installed when i run python setup.py install it gives my Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/test-easy-install-22642.write-test'.

Hence I went and installed python2.7 in my home directory which is in /userpath/Desktop/Python-2.7. 
Now can someone tell me how to do the following.

1. Change the python path to my Desktop/Python-2.7 ie when I run python it must not run from /usr/local/bin/python instead it must run from the python installed in my home/Desktop/Python-2.7 directory.
2. How to install setup tools to my home python directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have local Python deployments (with site-packages) you can create isolated Python environments with a tool called virtualenv:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

It answers your both questions

- Overrides default Python interpreter (after activation)
- Can have site-packages in any folder (no root access needed)